# load XML doesnt like large xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

So I've got some code which grabs an XML file from a 3rd party URL and stores it locally.

```
    function get_file($file, $local_path, $newfilename) { 
        echo "<br>Attempting message download for $file<br>"; 
        $out = fopen($local_path.$newfilename,"wb");
        if ($out == FALSE){ 
              print "File not opened<br>"; 
              exit; 
        } 

        $ch = curl_init(); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file); 

        curl_exec($ch); 
        echo "<br>Error is : ".curl_error ( $ch); 

        curl_close($ch); 

    }    
    get_file('URL FOR FILE', '../xml/', 'jobs.xml');
```

This works great - I can download the XML file and see it in my xml folder - its about 350mb.

I then try to load it to my database like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(CONNECTION DETAILS);

$sql = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '../xml/jobs.xml' REPLACE INTO TABLE jobs ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<job>'";

// check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

// Run the query
$mysqli->query($sql);

// Close the connection
$mysqli->close();
```

This part doesnt work...
The thing is, it works fine with a smaller XML test file.

Should LOAD XML be capable of processing a 350mb XML? If so, why isnt this code working?

If 350mb is too big, what can I do to get the xml data into my database (in columns etc). the XML file has about 130,000 entries.

Comment: What is the specific error you receive? Might not be size. You should use [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) to catch exceptions. In past, I found `LOAD XML` does not work if there are empty nodes. Also you must cohere to specific [MySQL XML structure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html), so not all raw content may work. Please post xml snippet.

Comment: Also you could try to do this on the comandline which will reduce the commands and therefore is less error-prone. E.g. you use PHP and you can run into PHP timeouts on this one - totally unrelated to the actual data-operation you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect mysql/mariadb to be able to process big data (bigger than memory) using a streaming approach. But I'd not expect it to eat whatever data format.

So there is a chance you have to translate the XML first, or you could even write your own application that uses a streaming parser to read the file and then run the appropriate SQL statements on your database.